# Prevent Wicket from generating HTML for container elements?

Tags: html, wicket

I'm running into an issue with Wicket generating markup for elements that programmatically need to be there, but not structurally. It's not messing anything up, but I like to keep the page as tidy as possible. It should be noted that I'm a front-end developer, so I'd like to keep my hands out of the java files, if possible.

Say I have the following HTML that's part of a component's template:

```
<ul class="configList" wicket:id="rows">
    <li wicket:id="cols">
        <div wicket:id="checkBoxThing"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the template for checkBoxThing:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="checkboxContainer">
        <label wicket:id="label"></label>
        <input  type="checkbox" wicket:id="checkbox" name="check" />
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

When the page is viewed, the resulting markup looks like this:

```
<ul class="configList>
    <li>
        <div>
          <div id="RandomWicketID">
             <label>Checkbox Label</label>
             <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Those two DIVs inside the LI aren't doing anything structurally or being used for a client-side script; they're just taking up space. Is there something I can do in the template to tell Wicket not to render them? I can't seem to find any parameters I can pass to accomplish this, and no one around the office seems to know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [<wicket:container>](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html#Wicket%2527sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket%253Acontainer) tag.

Note: if Wicket's configuration mode is set to development (the default IIRC) the wicket attributes & tags will still be present in the markup. If you change it to deployment, Wicket will strip them from the output (see https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-remove-wicket-markup-from-output.html).

configList:

```
<ul class="configList" wicket:id="rows">
    <li wicket:id="cols">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="checkBoxThing" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

checkBoxThing:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="checkboxContainer">
        <label>Checkbox Label</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </wicket:container>
</wicket:panel>
```

Result (in deployment mode):

```
<ul class="configList>
    <li>
        <label>Checkbox Label</label>
        <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<wicket:container>` eg.

```
<ul class="configList" wicket:id="rows">
    <li wicket:id="cols">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="checkBoxThing"></wicket:container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In general, see https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is Component#setRenderBodyOnly(true).